# Youtube Video's not playing in android(react-native)

Tags: android, react-native, android-youtube-api

I am developing a sample application which shows Youtube videos. It's working perfect on iOS, but on Android, instead of showing a play button, it shows a black screen with a spinner.

I am using the [`react-native-youtube`](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube) GitHub project to add the YouTube component.

```
 <YouTube
     apiKey={'xxxxxxxxxxxx'}
     videoId={xxxxxxxxx}  
     play={true}             
     fullscreen={false}       
     loop={false} 
     onReady={e => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
     onChangeState={e => this.setState({ status: e.state })}
     onChangeQuality={e => this.setState({ quality: e.quality })}
     onError={e => this.setState({ error: e.error })}
     style={[styles.articleImage, allTabFilterSelected ? {}
     styles.articleImageFilterTab]}
 />
```

On iOS, my application behaves fine with a play button that works. But on Android it's showing an empty black screen like this:

[image]

Please suggest some solution! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you [read this](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube#known-issues)?

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT! (Android Only):** The Android implementation of this component needs to have the **official YouTube app** installed on the device. Otherwise the user will be prompted to install / activate the app, and an error event will be triggered with SERVICE_MISSING/SERVICE_DISABLED.

Comment: Hi , i am running in emulator ! in installed you tube

Comment: Message showing like There was a problem to netWork [400]
tap to retry

Comment: did u try adding permission for the Internet in Android Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Login into **play store** and update **Youtube app** ... and that should make it work

Answer (score 0):

Add an API KEY for only android. Find an test key from your Google account

<YouTube **apiKey**='XXXXXXX' videoID= 'xxxxxx' />